# Combining two very large files ignoring the first sentence

Tags: string, awk

I want to combine two giant file each few hundred megabyte into a single file while ignoring the first line.

I wanted to use awk as I thought it should be the most optimized way. the way I'm doing it only ignores the first line of second file.
Any idea how to do make work or if there's a faster way to do it?

```
awk 'FNR!=NR && FNR==1 {next} 1' 'FNR!=NR && FNR==1 {next} 2' s_mep_{1,2}.out >> s_mep.out
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cat two files after each other but omit the last/first line respectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600170/how-to-cat-two-files-after-each-other-but-omit-the-last-first-line-respectively)

Comment: The awk suggestion in this article removes the first and the last line of the file.

Comment: It's the same basic principle(s) applied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR>1' file{1,2} > file_12
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`

```
(sed '1d' file_1 ; sed '1d' file_2) > new_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing to arbitrarily many files ...

```
for f in ... ; do
  tail -n +2 "$f" >> well_chosen_filename
done
```