# Concatenating CSV files in bash preserving the header only once

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cat, unix-head

Imagine I have a directory containing many subdirectories each containing some number of CSV files with the same structure (same number of columns and all containing the same header).

I am aware that I can run from the parent folder something like

```
find ./ -name '*.csv' -exec cat {} \; > ~/Desktop/result.csv
```

And this will work fine, expect for the fact that the header is repeated each time (once for each file).

I'm also aware that I can do something like `sed 1d <filename>` or `tail -n +<N+1> <filename>` to skip the first line of a file.

But in my case, it seems a bit more specialised. I want to preserve the header once for the first file and then skip the header for every file after that.

Is anyone aware of a way to achieve this using standard Unix tools (like find, head, tail, sed, awk etc.) and bash?

For example input files

```
   /folder1
            /file1.csv
            /file2.csv
   /folder2
            /file1.csv
```

Where each file has header:

`A,B,C` and each file has one data row `1,2,3`

The desired output would be:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

## Marked As Duplicate

I feel this is different to other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600170/how-to-cat-two-files-after-each-other-but-omit-the-last-first-line-respectively) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939685/combining-two-very-large-files-ignoring-the-first-sentence) specifically because those solutions reference file1 and file2 in the solution. My question asks about a directory structure with an arbitrary number of files where I would not want to type out each file one by one.

Comment: `once for the first file` which file is first? Or it makes no difference from which file the header is taken?

Comment: Makes no difference in this case :) all files contain the same header and I don't mind which comes first.

Comment: None of the linked questions are exact dup of this problem hence reopening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this `find + xargs + awk`:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 awk 'NR==1 || FNR>1'
```

`NR==1 || FNR>1` condition will be true for very first line in combined output or for every non-first line.

Comment: This assumes that `xargs` can process all the files using a single call to `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ {
> cat real-daily-wages-in-pounds-engla.tsv;
> tail -n+2 real-daily-wages-in-pounds-engla.tsv;
> } | cat
```

You can pipe the output of multiple commands through `cat`. `tail -n+2` selects all lines from a file, except the first.